# “Shed some color”

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase **"shed color"** mean though? 
The whole sentence which was a question goes like:

> Wanna shed some color for you?

For your information, the speaker is not a native speaker of English but still the speaker studied aboard in an English speaking country for a quite long time so I assumed the phrase itself would make some sense and I had did my research, you know, on google, internet and everything and I didn’t get my answer.

I’ve heard the phrases like, “shed light on something”, “shed tears “or “shed blood” and so on, but I’ve never heard of “shed color”. Hope my question is clear enough for you guys to understand and hopefully some native speakers can share some thoughts or answer my questions, thank you in advance.

Edited:

The whole thing (which was text messaging actually) went like (word by word):

> “Want to explore the possibilities to invest watches. I know you expert on this. Want to shed some colour fr u ?”

Hope it’s helpful and again thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to provide some more context, like the surrounding paragraph or conversation?

Comment: Sure,I will do it in minutes,thank you for the quick response though.

Answer (score 1):

That is an idiomatic phrase, but it doesn't appear to be used in a way that is familiar to me.

I am only aware of that phrase being used almost literally, such as:

> These flowers will shed some colour on a dreary garden.

Or very slightly figuratively, such as:

> These activities can shed colour on the dreariest day.

Also completely literally, such as:

> These flowers shed colour when handled, so wear gloves that you don't mind getting stained.

I have no idea what the person in the question might mean.

Comment: Thank you for the input SamBC! It denfinely helped me clarify as to how to use the phrase in some proper/common ways and yeah still I have no idea what did the speaker actually meant to say either.